# InvalidStateError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement

Tags: jquery

I have a input tag with type as file

```html
<input type="file" id="fileToUpload" name="file" tabindex="6"  value=""/>
```

When i am selecting the file it gives me an error.

> jquery-2.1.3.js:7350 Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to set the
>   'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a
>   filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.

I looked into the jQuery code and found that it is because of

```js
 hooks = jQuery.valHooks[this.type] || jQuery.valHooks[this.nodeName.toLowerCase()];

                // If set returns undefined, fall back to normal setting
                if (!hooks || !("set" in hooks) || hooks.set(this, val, "value") === undefined) {
                    this.value = val;
                }
```

a code snippet from jQuery file.

> jQuery.valHooks having object only for checkbox,radio,option and
>   select. There is no object for file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to do something here ? Could you give us your javascript code ?

Comment: I am trying to do some operation on  $("#fileToUpload").change(function () {
                if ($('#fileToUpload').val() != "") {
                    //Some Operation
                }
            }); but due to error on change is not fired.

Comment: So when you click on "select a file" the error pops up ?

Comment: Error doesn't pop up but due to error in console my code in . Change event is not executed.

Comment: So when you load the page the error is already in console ? What if you delete your function, the error is still there ? If so, I suggest you to change your jQuery version.

Comment: No... No error during page load.its when m selecting file console error is thrown and change event is not fired due to this error.

Comment: Your problem isn't explicit at all... The problem comes from your code not the one in the jQuery file ! Make a jsFiddle and I will help you

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, this is not even the good answer but i tried a quick fix and it worked.

```
//Just to remove error inside the console.
//If error exists then onChange event is not fired.
var fileHook = {
    get: function (elem) {
        return this.value;
    },
    set: function (elem, value) {
        return this.value = value;
    }
}
$.valHooks["file"] = fileHook;
```

Explaining Pros and Cons are welcome if any.